# How do I remove 'Python Games' from Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, python, linux

When you download Raspbian, there are 'Python Games' installed. Is there an easy/clean way of removing this from the system including the Menu?

I preferably want to get rid of whatever 'Minecraft Pi' is too.

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: Remove the games menu.
[image: Use the Main Menu Editor] Uncheck the Games category to hide it.

**Reboot** the pi (or restart the xserver) to update the menu.

Option 2 : Remove the games.

To remove Minecraft Pi:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge python-minecraftpi`

To remove python-games:

`rm -rf ~/python_games`

**Reboot** the pi (or restart the xserver) to update the menu.

The games were included by default to give students a starting point for making their own games.  This is generally regarded as a great way to motivate young people and encourage experimentation.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal, and type in

```
sudo rm -R /home/pi/python_games
```

This will delete the Python Games folder. Keep in mind you need to run this command with **sudo**.

If it is still listed in your Games, then you can try to look for the package in your installed packages. In the terminal, type in:

```
apt-cache pkgnames python | less
```

This will display all the packages whose name begins with "python".
You must find the games package in the list of all packages, and once you found it, in the Terminal enter:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
```

However, beware that the package *python-gamera* is not related to Python games, but it is a cross-platform documentation package.

Comment: I removed the folder, which is something I've seen suggested by others on different forums, but 'Python Games' is still showing up in the Games menu after using `apt-get purge python-pygame`. However I managed to get rid of Minecraft Pi using `apt-get remove --purge minecraft-pi python-minecraftpi`

Answer (score 0):

try typing the command

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pygame
```

then type `

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

for remove totally. for minecraft pi, just change command into

```
sudo apt-get remove minecraft-pi
```

then use **autoremove** again.